# in openshift, phantomjs crash

Tags: phantomjs, openshift

I try use phantomjs in openshift, but this crash.

searching the problem, I try `phantom.create` in the node terminal

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
phantom.create(function(ph){
... ph.exit();
... });
{ options:
   { prefix: '',
     response_limit: 131072,
     websocket: true,
     jsessionid: false,
     heartbeat_delay: 25000,
     disconnect_delay: 5000,
     log: [Function],
     sockjs_url: 'https://d1fxtkz8shb9d2.cloudfront.net/sockjs-0.3.min.js' },
  _events: { connection: [Function] },
  install: [Function] }
>
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EACCES
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1020:19)
    at listen (net.js:1061:10)
    at net.js:1143:9
    at asyncCallback (dns.js:68:16)
    at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:121:9)
```

phantom crash, and out of openshift the lines work fine.

any suggestion ?

### EDIT

I use a phantomjs downloaded from

http://phantomjs.org/download.html

https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2

Comment: So the only thing that you do is `exit`? [This](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12697) may be related. Have you tried to find out, what error this is?

Answer (score 0):

The `Error: listen EACCES` means that phantom is trying to listen on the wrong host/port for your gear. Since it looks like you're leveraging websockets, make sure that you're using the `$OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP` environment variable as your host and 8443 or 8000 (secure vs non-secure) for your ports.